# Vue - How to update Table data asynchronous

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vuetify.js

I am currentyl experiencing a weird problem with my vue table (I am using the vuetify framework). Basically I have a table with user permissions and checkboxes to see if a user has permission to do something or not. The table looks similar to this

```html
<v-data-table
  id="permission-table"
  v-model="permissionTable.selected"
  :headers="permissionTable.headers"
  :items="permissionTable.users"
  :item-key="login"
  :items-per-page="5"
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template v-slot:item.admin="{ item }">
    <v-checkbox class="cb-center" v-model="item.admin" @change="updateUserPermission(item)"></v-checkbox>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.responsible="{ item }">
    <v-checkbox class="cb-center" v-model="item.responsible" @change="updateUserPermission(item)"></v-checkbox>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.creator="{ item }">
    <v-checkbox class="cb-center" v-model="item.creator" @change="updateUserPermission(item)"></v-checkbox>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.delete="{ item }">
    <font-awesome-icon class="icon-clickable" icon="trash"  @click="deleteUser(item._id)"/>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

As you can see if the change event for the checkbox is triggered an updateUserPermission method is fired. This method will make an http request and receive the user information back from the server. So the behaviour is supposed to be. Enable admin permissions --> checkbox gets enabled --> response is beeing received and if e.g. the response says admin is still false (which I implemented for testing) the checkbox will be unchecked again. Which it should do as it is bound via v-model and the property.

Now on the created event I first fetch some users like this

```js
async created(){
    this.permissionTable.users = await getCurrentUsers();
},
```

As expected my table gets filled correctly. To update the permissions I fake a rest call at the moment with my updateUserPermissions beeing

```js
async updateUserPermissions(){
return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(async  () => {
      Object.assign(User, { admin: false });
      resolve(User);
    }, 2000);
  })
}
```

Now with my users added initially to the table everything works as expected. (first the checkbox gets checked but it gets unchecked after the response with admin:false gets returned) But if I add new users to this table via a method the following happens with updateUserPermissions.

The data gets set correctly. So the user object gets set to admin=false after 2 seconds. But it does not get updated in the view of the website. Here it is still checked. This only happens with items not added via created. The old entries still work correctly. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was this. As I am using an object that is already in data and push it into the array for the table, then add more keys to that object, the getters and setters for those won't get set.

To make this work there's two options. The first one here is my preferred

**Option 1**

Push a new object instead of a reference to an object already in data. So this would look like

```js
async addUserToSelection(){
  let user = Object.assign({},this.users.availableUsers.find(u => u.login === this.users.selected),{
    admin: false,
    creator: false,
    responsible: false
  });
  if(!this.userExistsInPermissionTable(user) && user._id){        
    try {        
      await addUserPermission(user);
      this.permissionTable.users.push(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }     
}
```

**Option 2**

Set the new Keys using the vm.$set method (I'm just showing what's different to Option 1)

```js
let user = this.users.availableUsers.find(u => u.login === this.users.selected)
this.$set(user, 'admin', false);
this.$set(user, 'creator', false);
this.$set(user, 'responsible', false);
```

As I said my personal preference would be Option 1 as in my opinion it is more approachable if you are not familiar with the special functions of vue and is more of a vanilla javascript approach.